# How to avoid reading half-written arrays spanning multiple chunks using zarr?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, zarr

In a multiprocess situation, I want to avoid reading arrays from a zarr group that haven't fully finished writing by the other process yet. This functionality does not seem to come out of the box with zarr.

While chunk writing is atomic in zarr, array writing seems not to be (i.e. while you can never have a half-written chunk, you can have a half-written array if said array spans multiple chunks).

In my concrete example, one process is writing to the `position` group. This group contains a 1D array with a chunksize of 100. All goes well if the array I'm writing is smaller than this chunksize. Larger arrays will be written into several chunks, but not all of them are written simultaneously.

A parallel process may then try to read the array and find only a first chunk. Zarr then blithely returns an array of 100 elements. Milliseconds later, the 2nd chunk is written, and a subsequent opening of the group now yields 200 elements.

I can identify a number of solutions:

1. A store/group lock which must be acquired before writing or reading the entire array. This works, but makes concurrent writing and reading a lot harder because chunk-level locking is better than group/store-level locking. For simple 1D arrays that are write once/read many, that's enough.
2. A store/group lock that does not allow reading the entire array while the array is write-locked. I don't know if such read/write locks exist in zarr, or if I should brew my own using the fasteners library. Again for more complex N-D arrays this means loss of performance.
3. Adjust my write/read code to obtain a lock based on the region to write or read (the lock key could be composed of the indices to write or chunks to write). This would have better performance but it seems absurd that this isn't out-of-the-box supported by zarr.

The zarr docs are a bit too succinct and don't delve very deep into the concept of synchronisation/locking, so maybe I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really get around using some form of synchronization.

Your best bet is to communicate from the writer process to the reader processes that something is ready to be consumed.

A simple `multiprocessing.Queue` would work if you are forking from the same process and each worker will operate on the array themselves.

If multiple workers are coordinating to consume the array in parallel a `multiprocessing.Barrier` or `multiprocessing.Event` might work better.

There does appear to be some built in synchronization in the zarr.core class, [synchronization](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/sync.html). Looking at the source code it appears that zarr locks per chunk, so you'll need to do something to coordinate your reads and writes.